# Project upgrade to Winter 16 in Eclipse. What would happen really?

Tags: eclipse, release, upgrade

When i trying to create a project in eclipse, i am getting an alert to upgrade to Winter 16. I accept that and saw a popup window displaying list of classes trigger xml. I clicked one it to see the difference and both seems to be same.

What would really happen when i upgrade my project to Winter 16? Experts please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't observe any changes, they were probably just white space changes (e.g. replacing spaces with tabs). Technically, the upgrade process is setting a new API version, refreshing the metadata, then updating any files that are not synchronized with the server. This is usually harmless unless you have data that has not been saved to the server (e.g. you observe changes in cls, trigger, page, etc files). Be aware that this can result in a loss of work if you have files that were not already synchronized, but you'll be able to use the "revert to previous version" option for any files that experienced a loss of code.

Comment: From that, it sounds like if you have scratch work in your org that you don't want in Eclipse, it could get pulled in unexpectedly?

Answer (score 5):

From [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_pro_project_upgrade.htm):

> When you create a Force.com project, it's designed to work with a specific version of the server. When the server is upgraded to the next version, your projects need to be updated so you can have access to the latest features and metadata